# How to convert CR2 to JPG or PNG?

Tags: image-processing, png, jpeg

I need to convert a lot of CR2 photos to either JPG or PNG, no editing. How to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Ufraw**

you can convert `.cr2` to `.jpeg` by ufraw.

```
sudo apt-get install ufraw
```

Right click on the file and select `open with ufraw`.

** You can also import them to Gimp with `gimp-ufraw` and then export as `.png` or `.jpeg`.

```
sudo apt-get install gimp-ufraw
```

Comment: Didn't work for my photos shot on Canon 700D. Unable to open file of type CR2.

Comment: Ufraw is dead since 2017 and not included in ubuntu any more since xenial.

Answer (score 57):

I'll go a different route... Use `ufraw-batch` not `ufraw`.

```
sudo apt-get install ufraw-batch

## This will output (not replace) the file with a new extension.
## foo.CR2 exported to foo.png
ufraw-batch --out-type png *.CR2
```

See `ufraw-batch --help` and `man ufraw-batch` for more info.

Comment: ufraw-batch is awesome!

Comment: `ufraw-batch --out-type png $(ls IMG_93{44..99}* 2>| cat)`

Comment: In some cases, ufraw-batch leads to a segmentation fault. It will successfully develop one RAW file, and then it stops. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ufraw/+bug/1768855 for further information.

Comment: this works like a charm!

Comment: If you see a segmentation fault error like @user258532 describes, you could loop over each photo individually. It's slow, but it seemed to work: `for filename in $(ls); do  ufraw-batch --out-type jpg $filename; done`

Comment: E: Package 'ufraw-bach' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 18):

## ufraw alternatives

The [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483379/how-to-convert-cr2-to-jpg-or-png/483380#483380) recommends to use ufraw, but ufraw's development has ceased as of June 2015 and it's not supported by current Ubuntu releases. See
[Ubuntu Bugtracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ufraw/+bug/1848044), which recommends *darktable* or *rawtherapee* as alternatives. Both tools are GU tools, but it is possible to use them from CLI.

**darktable:** [manual](https://www.darktable.org/usermanual/en/overview_chapter.html#darktable_cli_commandline_parameters), [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/darktable-cli.1.html)

Batch processing example:

```
for pic in *.CR2
do
     darktable-cli "$pic" "$(basename ${pic%.CR2}.jpg)"; 
done
```

**rawtherapee**: [manual](https://rawpedia.rawtherapee.com/Command-Line_Options#Example_2)

Comment: This worked for me, unlike `ufraw`, `dcraw` and `mogrify`, which all outputted very pink images.

Comment: problem with `darktable-cli` is that your can't run concurrent processes and it's pretty slow. If you're looking to make previews, `exiv2 -ep` is an alternative, if the raw files contain embedded jpegs

Comment: `darktable` did the job as of today, Sept 13, 2021. Sad the many once popular answers are merely the sign of the bygone times of ufraw support.

Answer (score 7):

For another alternative, [use `mogrify`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php):

```
mogrify -format png *.cr2
```

Comment: it should be stated that mogrify is part of imagemagick, which is available at https://www.imagemagick.org. however, mogrify uses ufraw-batch in the background, so might as well use that directly

Comment: +1 as mogrify circumvents the bug in ufraw-batch that leads to a segmentation fault (asper Sptember 2018)

Comment: This worked nicely. I just wish there was a verbose option because I didn't realize it was succeeding on a long-running job.

Answer (score 3):

Try [**nconvert**](http://www.xnview.com/en/nconvert/)

As command line tool 
OR
**[xnconvert](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnconvert/)** as GUI tool

Comment: Please explain how to use xnconvert.

Comment: This is now a Famous Question. We do not like these sort of answers. This should be deleted.

Comment: ./nconvert -out jpeg -truecolors /path/to/images/folder/*.CR2

Comment: It's not a helpful answer, but the xnconvert tool worked better for me than all of the other options. You have to download and install the .deb file (no PPA as far as I can tell) but the conversion process was fast and accurate, better colour reproduction than either ufraw or dcraw and faster than either batch process. Using it is reasonably easy, point it at a directory of CR2 files and tell it where to drop the JPEGs and click the button.

Answer (score 2):

The method that really worked for me:

You need `dcraw` and `ppmtojpeg` (install with apt)

```
for i in *.CR2; do dcraw -c $i | ppmtojpeg > $1.jpg; echo $i done; done
```

What it does: First convert CR2 to PPM with `dcraw` passing the output to `ppmtojpeg` which converts to JPG.

I found this [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1421624&s=7047f173080054204619b80579cd27c5&p=9840775#post9840775)

Comment: Since you mentioned apt, it's worth noting that in Debian derivatives, `ppmtojpeg` in included in the `netpbm` package (users may be confused if they search for a package with the same name as the binary).

Comment: Should be:
`for i in *.CR2; do dcraw -c $i | ppmtojpeg > $i.jpg; echo $i done; done`

Answer (score 2):

Create a bash file like foo.sh and execute as ./foo.sh in command line:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in $(ls)
do
ufraw-batch --out-type png $i
echo "conversion done $i"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble with ufraw since it produces a segmentation fault on elementary OS (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ufraw/+bug/1768855). I combined your answers (thanks!) and finally got a working version.

First get the right command for exiftool (as mentioned by Rafael):

```
exiftool -s2 -all -b -X -fXMP:XMP test.RAF  | grep Preview
```

which is in my case not -Composite:PreviewImage but:

```
File:PreviewImage
```

So you can use the batch script from Abu:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in *.RAF
do
exiftool -File:PreviewImage -b $i > $i.jpg
echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 2):

.cr2 files are apparently some kind of Canon digital camera raw format. Maybe that's what CR stands for?--"Canon Raw".

Anyway, I just recovered a bunch of them from a corrupted SD card from a digital camera, using `ddrescue` and `photorec` (installed by `sudo apt install testdisk`, and here's how I just converted hundreds of recovered .cr2 files to .png and .jpg images:

**Update after writing this answer:**

[I need to experiment more with this too]

CR2 files appear to be valid TIF files too, so you might also try simply changing the file extension from `.cr2` to `.tif` and then using tools to convert from `.tif` to `.jpg` or `.png`! I just renamed the file extension from `.cr2` to `.tif` and double-clicked it and my image viewer in Ubuntu 20.04 was able to open it just fine.

### How to convert a *single* .cr2 image to a .jpg or .png image

*Tested in Ubuntu 20.04.*

```bash
# First, install ImageMagick
sudo apt install imagemagick

# strip off the .cr2 extension from your file (this is required for some reason
# to make `convert` work)
mv myimage.cr2 myimage

# Create a JPG from that image. 
# - This creates `myimage.jpg`. The original `myimage` image remains intact.
convert myimage myimage.jpg
# Create a PNG image from that image
# - This creates `myimage.png`. The original `myimage` image remains intact.
convert myimage myimage.png
```

That's it!

Note: if `convert` won't work, try the fix I mention [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61700520/4561887).

### How to batch convert *hundreds* of .cr2 images into .jpg or .png images

In my case, I needed to convert *hundreds* of images from .cr2 to .png. Here is how I did that as fast as possible, using all 8 of my CPU cores at once:

```bash
cd path/to/all/of/your/cr2/images

# Move all .cr2 images into a "cr2" folder
mkdir cr2
mv *.cr2 cr2
cd cr2

# strip the extension (`convert` won't work if you don't do this first, for some
# reason)
# How to strip file extensions in bash:
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180272/114401
for file in *.cr2; do mv -- "$file" "${file%%.cr2}"; done

# Convert them all to PNG images now!
# - I learned about `xargs` from here:
#   https://stackoverflow.com/a/25532027/4561887 and in my answer here:
#   https://stackoverflow.com/a/76910116/4561887
# - Note: `-P "$(nproc)"` says to spawn as many parallel processes as you have
#   CPU threads, since `nproc` returns the number of hardware threads
#   (hyperthreaded "processors", or "cores") your computer has. So if `nproc`
#   shows you have 8 hardware threads, this will spawn 8 simultaneous `convert`
#   operations to speed this up!
ls | xargs -n 1 -P "$(nproc)" -I% convert % %.png

# When done, move all produced .png images to a "png" dir one level up, at the
# same level as the "cr2" dir we are currently in
mkdir ../png
mv *.png ../png/
```

### Going further: how to recover images from a corrupted camera SD card, memory card, drive, or disk (or just deleted files)

(This is how I got all of my .cr2 files above).

See my answer here: [Unix/Linux undelete/recover deleted files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/743566/114401)

### References

1. Converting images from .cr2 to .png or .jpg:

   1. [Google search for "linux convert .cr2 to jpg"](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+convert+.cr2+to+jpg&oq=linux+convert+.cr2+to+jpg&aqs=chrome..69i57.8362j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

      1. Very useful!: where I first learned about using `convert` to convert .cr2 images to .png. I also learned here that you have to *strip the .cr2 extension first to make it work!*: https://www.linuxshelltips.com/convert-raw-camera-image-to-jpeg-in-linux/
   2. Where I learned how to strip file extensions in bash: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180272/114401
   3. Where I learned how to use `xargs` to parallelize operations on files listed by `ls`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25532027/4561887
2. My answer where I used `xargs` with `-P "$(nproc)"` to unzip many password-protected files at once, in parallel: [Stack Overflow: unzip password protected zip in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76910116/4561887)

Answer (score 1):

You could also program a simple loop in the console.

For example (using the [fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_interactive_shell) console), and assuming the active directory only has RAW files.

```
set files (ls)
for i in $files
    dcraw $i
end
```

or

```
set files (ls)
for i in $files
    ufraw-batch --out-type=tif --out-depth $i
end
```

I use ufraw-batch that way because it often leads to an error, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ufraw/+bug/1768855 .

Answer (score 1):

In case you need preview the photos as an initial filtering step, here's what I do

1. install packages: `sudo apt-get install -y dcraw netpbm`
2. extract all thumbnails as jpeg: `for i in *.CR2; do dcraw -e $i ; done`
3. let my wife filter the images (the jpgs)
4. run the following .py script (`python3 rm_filtered_cr2.py`):

```
   import os
   files = os.listdir()
   for cr2_file in files:
       if cr2_file.endswith('.CR2'):
           thumbnail_file = cr2_file.replace('.CR2', '.thumb.jpg')
           if not os.path.exists(thumbnail_file):
               print("removing %s" % cr2_file)
               os.remove(cr2_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
exiftool -Composite:PreviewImage -b photo.CR2 > photo.jpg
```

Longer answer:

ufraw-batch conversion quality is very bad. Imagemagick uses ufraw under the hoods (unfortunately). dcraw is better, but still not great. The best solution I found out was to use exif to extract PreviewImage metadata. I believe that's generated by the camera itself.

Ref: https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6936&sid=9548c421f1bd69f192e632d06ca03dff&start=30#p130949