# ufraw fatal internal error on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I am trying to use ufraw to convert cr2 images to jpeg on Ubuntu 16.04. When I run the following, from the folder in which my images are located:

```
ufraw-batch --out-type jpg  *.CR2
```

I get the following:

```
ufraw-batch: Fatal internal error
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The same thing happens in ufraw GUI. Can anyone help?

Comment: You have typed 'ufraw'  ..! Have you installed ufraw or ufraw-batch ? Have you seen this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/483379/how-to-convert-cr2-to-jpg-or-png

Comment: Yep, I have seen all the posts available about ufraw here. And of course I installed them, it's hard for me to get that error if I haven't, is it?